# Photo has bright and darker on an aerial photo question

Tags: images, photo-editing, black, white

I am not very familiar how to manipulate with the photo i have has a bright and a darker in the same photos.  I do not know if this is a common or not .
I got this from a contractor that scanned many aerial photos however; I have a few of them that happens to have like this. I wanted to see if anyone has the same problem as mine ?

Donn't need to copy to another GIS Stackexchange as I already post there but have no luck

I discovered that the darker has 8 unsigned bit while the bright one has 16 unsigned bit... I'd like have the bright one to match with the darker in a 8 bit .

Is there a way around for me to fix this problem ?

I have tried to use breakpoint to find the similar match but no luck.  I split the two and tried to get the bright to change to similar to the dark one...

[image]

Comment: As you noted, the darker area *has more data* and you can't simply "create" data where none exists. [You can try to *visually* get the areas to appear the same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ltq7o.png). But due to the lack of data, the subtle greys are simply not present int he "light" side.

Comment: While looking at the image, (I could be wrong, but) I see that the right (lighter) side portion of the image almost looks like the righter most portion of the left (darker) side. Almost as if the lighter side was stamped in to fill the width of the image. I am referring to imagery, not luminosity.

Comment: @nocturns2 I see that too. Pieces of the right hand lighter section look like the same image as just to the left of them.  [See areas circled here](https://imgur.com/bRkqKxe). If this was taken using film, it could have been caused by a mechanical fault in the camera which caused a double exposure on just one part of the image. If that's the case, then the area on the right is probably unrecoverable.

Comment: @BillyKerr   - Bill it is good you catch that.  I didn't realize that ....I will need to look into that area and review . This area is on the National  Forest in Colorado where I am working on these aerial photos. I will need to have discuss with my co-worker about this...